# How to extend template in angular 2?

Tags: javascript, meteor, typescript, angular

Imagine following:

`<app></app>`

here is app where router renders my template for each url, controlled by Typescript @selector. Router decide what to execute and controller work like this:

```
@Component({
selector: "app"})


@View({
templateUrl: "client/courses-list/courses-list.html",
directives: [NgFor, CoursesForm, RouterLink, AccountsUI]}) export class CoursesList {courses:[1,2,3,4,5]}
```

What i have now, is router-directed rendering of each component with its own controller and template. Thats cool, so how can I now extend my base.html, or if want to have two components on one page, which extended.
In Django we do:

```
<nav>menu one two three</nav>
{%block content%}
{%endblock%}
<footer></footer>
```

So i need app, which extending from base html and everything in app is anular2-controllable. So it should be within  
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

> So it should be within

You *index.html* would be :

```
<nav>menu one two three</nav>
<main>
  // components go here
</main>
<footer></footer>
```

And then *angular router* would place the right content based on the route. More : http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/06/16/routing-in-angular-2.html